# Invalid variable name error in Android build.grade

Tags: android

**My code:**

> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options
>   common to all sub-projects/modules.
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
>
>         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>         // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     } }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>     delete rootProject.buildDir }
> ```

Here the error log:

> Error:(1, 0) Cause: startup failed:
>       build file 'D:\Doctor\build.gradle': 1: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: 
>       . At [1:1]  @ line 1, column 1.
>          // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
>          ^
>
> ```
> 1 error
>
> <a href="openFile:D:\Doctor\build.gradle">Open File</a>
> ```

Comment: format your question properly

Comment: Error:(1, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'D:\Doctor\build.gradle': 1: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: 
. At [1:1]  @ line 1, column 1.
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
   ^

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and found a solution to fix it. However, I do not know how the problem occurs in the first place.

The problem is that the build.gradle file is corrupted. I did a hex dump of that file and here's what I found:

```
$ hexdump -C build.gradle | more
00000000  ef bb bf 2f 2f 20 54 6f  70 2d 6c 65 76 65 6c 20  |...// Top-level |
00000010  62 75 69 6c 64 20 66 69  6c 65 20 77 68 65 72 65  |build file where|
00000020  20 79 6f 75 20 63 61 6e  20 61 64 64 20 63 6f 6e  | you can add con|
00000030  66 69 67 75 72 61 74 69  6f 6e 20 6f 70 74 69 6f  |figuration optio|
00000040  6e 73 20 63 6f 6d 6d 6f  6e 20 74 6f 20 61 6c 6c  |ns common to all|
00000050  20 73 75 62 2d 70 72 6f  6a 65 63 74 73 2f 6d 6f  | sub-projects/mo|
00000060  64 75 6c 65 73 2e 0d 0a  0d 0a 62 75 69 6c 64 73  |dules.....builds|
00000070  63 72 69 70 74 20 7b 0d  0a 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 72  |cript {....    r|
00000080  65 70 6f 73 69 74 6f 72  69 65 73 20 7b 0d 0a 20  |epositories {.. |
```

Notice that the file begins with the hex values ef bb bf.  Those characters are not normally displayable, so you're not aware that they are in your file.  Those bad character is what's causing the issue. You need to get rid of them.  I don't know if everyone that runs into this problem will have those same values, but build.grade should be a text file those aren't displayable text characters.  I noticed that even if you delete the first line those bad characters still remain in the file, and you'll run into a different error. In my case it said it could not find "buildscript()". What I did to correct the problem was to go into an editor select the first line to the end of the file and copy the contents.  I then opened up a new editor and pasted the contents and saved the file. I saved it to build2.gradle.  I then deleted build.gradle and then renamed build2.gradle back to build.gradle. I did another hexdump and saw that those bad characters were gone.  I was then able to sync my project.

I have no idea how those bad characters got into the file, but here's more or less what I had done:  I had copied the entire contents of one project into a new project location and in the process of syncing and making the new project I ran into this issue. I also had changed from android 8.0 to 8.1 and gradle 4.2 to 4.4. Android Studio detected some issue and requested that I close the project and reopen it, so I did that. I for some reason suspect that's when the file became corrupted, but I don't know for sure.